# Make a variable name a variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have a variable "jobNo" which changes between 1 and 5 depending on user input. I have another 5 variable: "J1C", "J2C", "J3C" ...

How do I place the variable "jobNo" within the other 5 variables so that when jobNo=3 for example I will be able to say:

J3C = 0

I have tried:
"J" & jobNo & "C" = 0

but get errors. How would I do this please?

Comment: use arrays instead: `JC(jobNo)=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is the same as what **@simoco** commented.  Use an `Array`:

```
Dim JC(1 to 5) As Double
JC(1) = 0
JC(2) = 0
JC(3) = 0
JC(4) = 0
JC(5) = 0
```

Comment: Is there no way of doing it similar to how it is shown in my post? I ask because if I change it to an array, I have to go through all my code and replace it and there are many similar variables so I cant simply use the replace button.

Comment: @user3508196 As far as I know, `VBA` does not support this kind of functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was just being lazy and have changed them now :)

Answer (score 0):

You really should use arrays, not doing so, in this case, is very bad programming...

But if it is not possible to change everything you can create this:

```
Sub VBP(jobNo, J1C, J2C, J3C, J4C, J5C)
Select Case jobNo
 Case 1
  J1C = 0
 Case 2
  J2C = 0
 Case 3
  J3C = 0
 Case 4
  J4C = 0
 Case 5
  J5C = 0
End Select
End Sub
```

and then call it like this:

```
VBP jobNo, J1C, J2C, J3C, J4C, J5C
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly because I hate the vba `Array` you could use a `Collection` object

```
Dim jobNos As New Collection
Sub intializejobNos
    With jobNos
       .Add 0, "J1C"
       .Add 0, "J2C"
       .Add 0, "J3C"
       .Add 0, "J4C"
       .Add 0, "J5C"
   End With
End Sub

Sub changeJobNo(jobNo As String, val AS Variant)
OnError GoTo Handler
    With jobNos  
        .Remove jobNo
        .Add val, jobNo
    End With
Exit_changeJobNo: 
    Exit Sub
Handler: 
   Msgbox "Job Number " & jobNo & " Does not exist in the collection."
   GoTo Exit_changeJobNo
End Sub

Sub addJobNo(jobNo As Integer, val AS Variant)
   jobNos.Add val, "J" & jobNo & "C"
End Sub
```

This way you can intialize the `jobNos` `Collection` whic hwill have a completely variable size without the need to `ReDim` and then you can change the values where needed and you can then use dynamic functions like you want i.e.

```
Function getJobNo(jobNo AS Integer) As Variant
   If jobNos.Count = 0 Then
     initializejobNos
   End If
   getJobNo = jobNos("J" & jobNo & "C")
End Function
```

Obviously some additional Error Handling should be put in place but I find `Collection` objects far easier and more concise than using native VBA `Array`s.

Comment: Right, the way to complicate stuff to the extreme...if you can do it faster with arrays and writing much less... this is the way to go...sudo...

Comment: Not over complicating expanding but thanks for the comment. I believe in designing something to be as expandable as possible which is what I have done what happens when he wants to dynamically add or remove job in the future. I have removed my comment since it seems to have offended you greatly :(

Comment: You must recognize that it was not a fare comment :) No hard feelings. Look, collections are very versatile, I totally agreed. I am only talking for this particular case. Arrays will be about hundreds of time faster and with less code. I think we are over complicating the OP question... Maybe we are both right :)